# Diagnosing Windows 8 boot issue

Tags: windows-8

I've got an issue with a Windows 8 Professional install where, seemingly randomly, it will hang on boot (no new software installed before it happens and no updates installed).

The automatic repair process (system restore) fixes the issue after a couple of reboots, but I'd like to try and figure out the underlying cause (not least because of the complications I have when it happens and I have bitlocker enabled on the drive).

So the question is, does windows 8 log what changes it makes when it carries out the system restore process or are there any other logs I could look at to get a picture of what's causing the system to hang on boot?

Thanks

Comment: I've had the same problems with two Windows 8 machines now. For some reason it eventually resolves itself... after three or four attempts of applying updates and then rolling back those updates. I never did find out what caused it, I was just happy that it sorted itself out.

Comment: Does Event Viewer show anything?

Answer (score 0):

one of the most common scenarios when windows 8 would fail to  start properly is "**if windows 8 is  installed in an older machine. the problem arises due to hybrid boot actually which conflicts with the fact that windows 8 tries to use the preloaded drivers and services**". For older machines some drivers might behave in their legacy manner and hence the problem. you could try disable fast boot is such cases.

to disable fast boot follow the instructions below

1. press windows key and start searching for power settings
2. click/tap on **change what the power buttons do**
3. click/tap on **change settings that are currently unavailable**
4. bypass UAC and unucheck **Turn on fast startup (recommended)**